# How to Launch browsers for each single testng XML file in selenium

Tags: xml, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

I have two testng XML files
    eg : testng1.xml & testng2.xml

I need to execute these two XML files in different browsers or Same browsers parallely. Kindly suggest me how to achieve this scenario.

Comment: Can you add those files in question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's depends on how you configured your class in `testing.xml` file.
You can even use single `testing.xml` file to run your test parallel on same browser or different browser as well.

For configuration you can use below sample file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">

<suite name="Parallel Test" parallel="classes">
   <test name="Functional_Test_1">
     <parameter name="browser" value="PhantomJS" />
    <classes>    
          <class name="com.simpletest.DriverSerup"/>
   </classes> 
  </test> 
     <test name="Functional_Test_2">
       <parameter name="browser" value="chrome" />
     <classes>      
        <class name="com.simpletest.DriverSerup"/>
     </classes> 
  </test>    
</suite>
```

And this is how you can setup browser to execute Test:

```
package com.simpletest;

import org.testng.annotations.Parameters;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class DriverSerup {

    @BeforeTest
    @Parameters("browser")
    public void setUp(String browser)
    {

        switch(browser)
        {
        case "chrome":

            // Write the code here for open chrome browser
            System.out.println("For Browser : " + browser);
            break;
        case "PhantomJS":
            // Write the code here for open PhantomJS browser
            System.out.println("For Browser : " + browser);
            break;
        default :
            System.out.println("Broweer choice not available");     

        }
    }

}
```

Mention all your classes in both `<test>` tags as you have created to automate.

Or if you have 2 `testing.xml` then configure like :

**testing1.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">

<suite name="Parallel suite 1" >
   <test name="Functional_Test_1">
     <parameter name="browser" value="PhantomJS" />
    <classes>    
          <class name="com.simpletest.DriverSerup"/>
   </classes> 
  </test> 
</suite>
```

**testing2.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Parallel suite 2">
     <test name="Functional_Test_2">
       <parameter name="browser" value="chrome" />
     <classes>      
        <class name="com.simpletest.DriverSerup"/>
     </classes> 
  </test>    
</suite>
```

And here you have to create suite of suites i.e. **combinesuite.xml** :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="suite of suites"  parallel="classes" thread-count="2" >
    <suite-files>
        <suite-file path="testing1.xml" />
        <suite-file path="testing2.xml" />
    </suite-files>
</suite>
```

**Note :** don't forget to mention `parallel` attribute in `suite` tag for parallelism.

Comment: I have separate property file where I can mention which browser to launch, which user to login, which URL to navigate.

Comment: Based on the property file configurations, a set of action has been performed.

Comment: In property file I have mentioned Browser = Chrome, so i need to run two testng.xml files in two browsers at a same time.

Comment: You have to configure browser parameter in testing.xml as i have given the example  to run your test as per your choice instead of property file.

Answer (score 0):

For my scenario, testng2.xml file gets triggered only after all the tests are executed in testng1.xml file.

Please see the below example.

**Testng1.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">

<suite name="Parallel suite 1" >
  <test name="Functional_Test_1">
   <parameter name="browser" value="Chrome" />
    <classes>    
      <class name="com.simpletest.sample1"/>
    </classes> 
  </test> 

   <test name="Functional_Test_2">
    <classes>    
       <class name="com.simpletest.sample2"/>
     </classes> 
  </test> 
</suite>
```

**Testng2.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">

<suite name="Parallel suite 2" >
  <test name="Functional_Test_3">
   <parameter name="browser" value="Chrome" />
    <classes>    
      <class name="com.simpletest.demo1"/>
    </classes> 
  </test> 

   <test name="Functional_Test_4">
     <classes>    
       <class name="com.simpletest.demo2"/>
     </classes> 
  </test> 
</suite>
```

Then I created **combinesuite.xml** file where I have configured two testng.xml files and triggered it.

In this case, **testng2.xml** file gets triggered only after **testng1.xml** file gets completed.

So, can help me how to run these two xml files parallely in any browsers.