# Launching different selenium Grid tests in different browsers at the same time

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng

I am having a selenium grid hub and a selenium node :

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.14.0.jar -role hub
java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=c:\selenium\chromedriver.exe -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.14.0.jar -role node -hub http://10.X.X.X:4444/grid/register
```

I have 2 different tests in 2 separate files and classes class A and class B:

The first one, the driver:

```
 @BeforeTest
 public void setup() throws MalformedURLException {

     nodeUrl = "http://10.133.2.80:4444/wd/hub";

     DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
     capabilities.setBrowserName("chrome");
     capabilities.setPlatform(Platform.WINDOWS);
     driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(nodeUrl), capabilities);

 }
```

And the second one:

```
 @BeforeTest
 public void setup() throws MalformedURLException {

     nodeUrl = "http://10.133.2.80:4444/wd/hub";

     DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
     capabilities.setBrowserName("chrome");
     capabilities.setPlatform(Platform.WINDOWS);
     driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(nodeUrl), capabilities);
}
```

Now what I want is to run them at the same time, on 2 separate chrome browsers, how would I do it ? I am using testng.

Answer (score 0):

You can use parameters in your testng.xml runner file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">

<suite name="TestSuite" thread-count="2" parallel="tests" >

 <test name="ChromeTest">

 <parameter name="browser" value="Chrome" />

   <classes>

     <class name="parallelTest.CrossBrowserScript"> </class>

  </classes>

 </test>


 <test name="FirefoxTest">

 <parameter name="browser" value="Firefox" />

  <classes>

    <class name="parallelTest.CrossBrowserScript"></class>

  </classes>

 </test>

</suite>
```

And in your @BeforeTest you can do something like bellow:

```
@BeforeTest
    @Parameters("browser")
    public void setup(String browser) throws Exception{
        //Check if parameter passed from TestNG is 'firefox'
        if(browser.equalsIgnoreCase("firefox")){
        //create firefox instance
            System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.marionette", ".\\geckodriver.exe");
            driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        }
        //Check if parameter passed as 'chrome'
        else if(browser.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome")){
            //set path to chromedriver.exe
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",".\\chromedriver.exe");
            //create chrome instance
            driver = new ChromeDriver();
        }
        else{
            //If no browser passed throw exception
            throw new Exception("No Browser");
        }
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
```

This question could help as well:
[How to Launch browsers for each single testng XML file in selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45707631/how-to-launch-browsers-for-each-single-testng-xml-file-in-selenium)

**BUT** you need to use one xml file with multiple tests tags as above.

Comment: Hi @Nael Abd eljawad, as i am using grid hub/node:        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
        capabilities.setBrowserName("chrome");
        capabilities.setPlatform(Platform.WINDOWS);
        driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(nodeUrl), capabilities); is it possible to replace the capabilities with the driver from your BeforeTest codes

Comment: Yes you can, but make sure that the browsers are in your node configurations. 
What configurations your node has?